# INSERT values in array of struct in a hive table

Tags: arrays, struct, hive

I tried this query :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table_name
PARTITION(col1,col2)
values(
struct_nstd((q),(a),(z),(w),(s),(x),(c),(d),(e),(r),(f),(v),(b),(g),(t),(y),(h),(n),(m),(j),(u));
)
;
```

datatype of all values in struct = string

I am getting error as :

```
Semantic Exception [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file for insert values Expression of type TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert/values
```

i have already tried combination of braces to insert value into array of struct

Answer (score 0):

Please create a dummy table first with atleast one row and then do a insert eg -

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table_name
PARTITION(col1,col2)
values(
struct_nstd((q),(a),(z),(w),(s),(x),(c),(d),(e),(r),(f),(v),(b),(g),(t),(y),(h),(n),(m),(j),(u));
) from dummytable limit 1;
```

Comment: Did it work for you ? - if yes, please accept the answer and close it :)